# Call a PL/SQL function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I'm trying to call a PL/SQL function I created with the following instructions :

```
variable rep number
execute :rep:=sal_ok_F2('MANAGER',100);
print rep;
```

But I obtain an error message saying that the variable rep is not declared, isn't the line "variable rep number" supposed to be the declaration of this variable ?

Comment: `variable rep number` defines a SQL\*Plus variable. But the assignment operator `:=` only works with a PL/SQL variable.

Comment: Are you running this as a statement or as a script? (Assuming you're using SQL Developer...)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - the `:rep` reference lets you use the it as a bind variable, so that assignment is fine. (I'm pretty sure you know that really...) Depending on the client, but if `variable` works then it looks like SQL*Plus or more likely SQL Developer.

Comment: Assuming the return value of  `sal_ok_F2` function is a SQL type that can be casted to `number` your example is a valid sequence of `sqlplus` commands. Either your example is not the same than your real case or you're not running this with `sqlplus`.

Comment: I'm using sqlplus. Well maybe it's due to the fact I use the express edition of oracle database that might not contain all the functionnalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
declare 
  rep number;
begin
  select sal_ok_F2('MANAGER',100) into rep from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(rep);
  --or
  rep := sal_ok_F2('MANAGER',100);
  dbms_output.put_line(rep);
end;
```

Comment: Your script works but I have to use the method of my first post, and by the way how do you print the value of the variable rep with your method ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes indeed!